# How to load data from PostgreSQL in chunk with psycopg2

Tags: python, pandas, psycopg2, parquet

I want to load batches from table iteratively and save each batch in .parquet format.
The problem is I don't understand how can I do it with psycopg2.

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
records = cursor.fetchmany(size=5)
pd.DataFrame(data=records, columns=columns).to_parquet(...)
```

Code above select more than 5 rows.

I want to do something like:

```
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname, user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    records = cursor.fetchmany(size=5) #iterator with batches
    for batch in records:
        pd.DataFrame(data=records, columns=columns).to_parquet(...)
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty example:

```
with con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute(qry)
    for row in cur:
        records = cur.fetchmany(2)
        pd.DataFrame(data=records, columns=columns).to_parquet(...)
```